# Function to read rows from view and update or insert into tabel

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I need to write code in Postgres, where I'll read data rows from a view and insert into another table if it does not exist. If data row is present in table then it should get updated with new values.

Comment: if you run 9.5 you can use new "upsert" - `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT`

Comment: @VaoTsun I am using 9.1

Comment: well then, give us what code you have so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

Comment: @VaoTsun I have to write from scratch 
create function test_stag() returns setof view_name as 'select * from view_name;' language 'sql';

Answer (score 0):

Write sql queries to display data in Data Output export the data it's in CSV(comma separated values) file.
Then using cmd insert or update table.

Command :- PATH>psql -U postgres -d databaseName -h postgresAddress
        or PATH>psql dbname

/*Copy command*/
databaseName=# \copy tableName FROM 'path/filename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV